# Converting between types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I'm trying to make a simple function to return a centered string of text in Haskell, but I'm having trouble just finding how much padding to insert either side. I have this:

```
center padLength string = round ((padLength - (length string)) / 2)
```

Which gives the following error:

```
No instance for (Fractional Int)
  arising from a use of '/'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Fractional Int)
In the first argument of 'round', namely
  '((padLength - (length string)) / 2)'
In the expression: round ((padLength - (length string)) / 2)
In an equation for `center':
    center padLength string = round ((padLength - (length string)) / 2)
```

How can I (basically) convert from an Double (I think) to an Int?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is not that you can't convert a Double to an Int — `round` accomplishes that just fine — it's that you're trying to do division on an Int (`padLength - length string`). The error message is just telling you that Int is not an instance of `Fractional`, the typeclass for numbers that can be divided.

In general, you could use `fromIntegral (padLength - length string)` to turn it into a Double, but in this case, you can simply use integer division directly:

```
center padLength string = padLength - (length string) `div` 2
```

`` a `div` b `` is just a nicer way of writing `div a b`; you can use any function as a binary operator like this.

Comment: Why does it need the `? I'm a bit new to Haskell

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use fractional division `/` on operands of integral type, but that's not defined.

You should either convert the operands to Double before dividing (using `fromIntegral`), or use integral division `div`.